# The union of $x$ and $y$ axis with subspace topology is not locally euclidean

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The union of $x$ axis and the $y$ axis is not manifold .
It is Hausdorff and second countable, but it's not locally Euclidean.
I was trying to prove it by contradiction, but I can't, the issue is supposed to be with the $(0, 0)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Union of $x$-axis and $y$-axis is not a manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086739/union-of-x-axis-and-y-axis-is-not-a-manifold) and this [How to prove a cross is not locally homeomorphic to an euclidean space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467251/how-to-prove-a-cross-is-not-locally-homeomorphic-to-an-euclidean-space)

Comment: Can I apply the same argument if I want to proof the sets the union of the tow triangles <0,e1,e2> and <0,-e1,e2> it's not a closed manifold ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$ in subspace topology. Suppose it homeomorphic to open interval $I \subset  \mathbb{R}$ (as is the case with any other point except $(0, 0)$). Note that if you remove point $(0, 0)$ from the union of the $x$- and $y$-axes, you have **four connected components** and if you remove the corresponding point in $I$ you will have **two connected components**. By this you cannot have homeomorphism between them (by a property of continuous maps).